# Is there a name for the differential operator $\nabla\otimes$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-operators, outer-product

There seems to be quite a few names for differential operators involving $\nabla$:

- gradient: $\nabla$
- divergence: $\nabla\cdot$
- curl: $\nabla\times$
- laplacian: $\nabla^2$

I was wondering whether there is a name also for: $\nabla\otimes$

Comment: Is that componentwise application of nabla onto a vector of multidinensional functions?

Comment: I guess...don't know exactly what you mean. I mean: $(\nabla\otimes\mathbf{f})_{ij}=\nabla_if_j$, i.e. the result is a second-order tensor of differentials of the components of $\mathbf{f}$.

Comment: $(\nabla_i f_j)_{ij}$ is just the transpose of the Jacobian...

Comment: Is $\nabla_i$ supposed to be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$?